# Find the probability of random variable being greater than another

Tags: random-variable, joint-distribution

So here's the following question and I'll explain my solution so far, just want to know if I'm on the right track.

Let X, Y : Ω → R be independent random variables on a probability space (Ω, F, P)
such that X is distributed according to the beta distribution β2,1, and Y according to the exponential
distribution E2. Determine the probability that X > 2Y .

So I know that P (X>2Y) is the same as saying P (X-2Y >0). So I figured I could just find the density of X-2Y and thus it's CDF. 
I used the fact that they are independent to show that their joint density is:  $P (x,y) = 4xe^{-2y}$. (Sorry for no latex abilities).

I then integrated this over the intervals (0,$\infty$) dy and (0,(c+2y)) dx (where c is some constant such that x < c-2y) to find that the density is equal to 2(c^2 + c + 1).

Where exactly do I go from here? Can I simply integrate again wrt z where z=x-2y? Or have I just messed it up entirely?

Comment: I have edited in some LaTeX and with that as a guide you can probably do the rest.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already integrating over the joint density, bringing in an additional variable $c$ is just adding unnecessary complication to a simple problem.  Given the joint density $f_{X,Y}$ for random variables $0 \leqslant X \leqslant 1$ and $Y \geqslant 0$ you obtain the probability of your event by integration over the joint density:

$$\mathbb{P}(X > 2Y) = \int \limits_0^1 \int \limits_0^{x/2} f_{X,Y}(x,y) dy dx.$$

Try using your joint density to evaluate this probability, and then compare your result to empirical tests using comparisons simulated values from the specified marginal distributions.

Also, **spend an hour to learn some basic Latex!**